# How to programatically run sequelize seeders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to NodeJS and Sequelize and am trying to execute the sequelize seeders on project startup.

Here is an example of one of my seed functions.

`filePath: src/database/seeders/20220402125658-default-filters.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Filters', [
      {
        id: 'b16c15ce-9841-4ea5-95fb-0d21f8cd85f0', // TODO: use uuid4()
        name: 'Amount Filter',
        maxAmount: 200.0,
        minAmount: 0.2,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
    ]);
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.bulkDelete('Filters', null, bulkDeleteOptions);
  },
};
```

In my index.js file I am executing sequelize.sync() which synchronizes my database model.
This is working great, but I want to also execute the seed code above when the sync is complete.

`filePath: src/database/index.js`

```
db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
// execute seeders here ...
});
```

Do you have any idea how can I do that ?
The seeding is working correctly when I use it through npx command: `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`, but I want to do it automatically on project start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach may be to write a script that runs the migrations/seeds via the Sequelize CLI and add in your `package.json` a `start` script that calls it, e.g. `./run-migrations.sh && node .` (or maybe just `sequelize-cli db:migrate && sequelize-cli db:seed:all && node .`). Then just run `npm run start` to start the application.

---

Otherwise, from the looks of it, Sequelize has the [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) library for programmatically applying migrations/seeds. See [the comment in this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/issues/24#issuecomment-591313032) for how you might do this.

I'll copy the code here in case it's lost:

> ```js
> /* <PROJECT_ROOT>/migrations.js */
> var Umzug = require("umzug");
> var models = require("./models");
>
> var migrationsConfig = {
>   storage: "sequelize",
>   storageOptions: {
>     sequelize: models.sequelize
>     // modelName: 'SequelizeMeta' // No need to specify, because this is default behaviour
>   },
>   migrations: {
>     params: [
>       models.sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
>       models.sequelize.constructor
>     ],
>     path: "./migrations", // path to folder containing migrations
>     pattern: /\.js$/
>   }
> };
>
> var seedsConfig = {
>   storage: "sequelize",
>   storageOptions: {
>     sequelize: models.sequelize,
>     modelName: 'SequelizeData' // Or whatever you want to name the seeder storage table
>   },
>   migrations: {
>     params: [
>       models.sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
>       models.sequelize.constructor
>     ],
>     path: "./seeds", // path to folder containing seeds
>     pattern: /\.js$/
>   }
> };
>
> var migrator = new Umzug(migrationsConfig);
> var seeder = new Umzug(seedsConfig);
>
> module.exports = () => migrator.up().then(() => seeder.up());
>
> /* <PROJECT_ROOT>/index.js */
> var migrations = require("./migrations");
>
> // Run migrations & seeds
> migrations().then(function() {
>   console.log("Migrations completed");
> });
> ```